# Why do these functions have the same type after erasure?

Tags: java, scala, generics

```scala
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]], list2: Option[List[X]]): Option[List[X]]  
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]], elem: Option[X]): Option[List[X]]
```

The compiler says that these two functions have same type after erasure

```scala
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]],list2: Option[List[X]]): Option[List[X]] at line 122 and
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]],elem: Option[X]): Option[List[X]] at line 131
have same type after erasure: (list1: Option, list2: Option)Option
```

Why does the `Option[List[X]]` and `Option[X]` become same after erasure?
How can I make them different?

Comment: "Why does the `Option[List[X]]` and `Option[X]` become same after erasure?" – Do you know what Type Erasure means? It literally means that the generic types are erased. In other words, *all* `Option[Something]`  have the same erased type, since the `Something` gets erased. So, `Option[List[X]]` and `Option[X]` both become `Option`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does the `Option[List[X]]` and `Option[X]` become same after erasure?

Because the generic type parameter of `Option[...]` is erased (so both `X` and `List[X]` are erased) so both methods will have the same signature.

> How can I make them different?

One approach - adding dummy implicit parameter to one of the methods so they have different signatures:

```scala
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]], list2: Option[List[X]]): String = "1"
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]], elem: Option[X])(implicit d: DummyImplicit): String = "2"

println(merge(Some(List(1)), Some(List(2)))) // 1

println(merge(Some(List(1)), Some(2))) // 2
```

For Scala 3 (thanks to [@Gaël J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389127/ga%C3%ABl-j) for pointing that out) [`@targetName`](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/other-new-features/targetName.html) annotation can be used to resolve the ambiguity:

```scala
import scala.annotation.targetName
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]], list2: Option[List[X]]): String = "1"
@targetName("merge_element")
def merge[X](list1: Option[List[X]], elem: Option[X]): String = "2"

println(merge(Some(List(1)), Some(List(2)))) // 1
println(merge(Some(List(1)), Some(2))) // 2
```

Comment: In Scala 3, you could use `@targetName` to distinguish them.